# Create a counter for "yes" and "no" selections from radio buttons using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function, input

I've been reading the site's question, but I haven't  found any that helps me find a solution to my problem:

I need to create a counter that shows how many times the "Yes" option was selected in the form, and how many times the "No" option was selected in the form. Then, I need to calculate a percentage based on the number of "Yes" selections against the total number of choices.

Here's the HTML:

```
        <section>
        <h2>Cumplimiento 1</h2>
            <form class="form3">
            <fieldset class="Compliance">
                <label class="form3header1" for="complianceperc">Cumplimiento (%)</label>
                <span class="percentage" type="number" id="complianceperc" name="complianceperc"></span>

                <label class="form3item1" for="yescount">Sí (cantidad)</label>
                <span id="price" class="counter"></span>    
                
                <label class="form3item2" for="yescount">No (cantidad)</label>
                <span class="counter"></span>

                </fieldset>
            </form>
            
        </section>
```

And here's the JavaScript (based on other answers in stackoverflow):

```
$('.counter').text($(':radio:checked').length);

$('input[type=radio]').change(function(){
  $('.counter').text($(':radio:checked').length);
});
```

And this is one of the radio button groups:

```
<label class="form4item1">1. ¿El Asesor de Servicio comienza a atender al Cliente en los primeros 2 minutos?</label>
            <input class="form4item1radio1" type="radio" name="question1" id="a" value="Accept">
            <input class="form4item1radio2" type="radio" name="question1" id="b" value="Reject">
            <textarea class="form4item1comment" placeholder="Escribe tus notas aquí"></textarea>
```

All I can get is a counter that shows the number of checked radio buttons, which is close but not quite what I need. I am a beginner in JavaScript, so while I realize I have much to learn, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I can't answer you about this. but if you want to make a poll on a webpage showing how many people clicked on yes or no, sounds like a backend thing. Cause If you do it in the frontend then the value will be of yours only. Using backend you can maintain a database of users with what they clicked and calculate the percentage super easily.

Comment: Since you have some idea about JavaScript I would highly recommend you to learn node.js which is used in backend development along with database management system like(sqlite or MySql).

Comment: Thank you for your guidance, Miran. I definitely still have a long way to go to fully familiarize with JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put `id` in the label to show percentage each `label`. And the `jquery change` function that you already made is **the operation to calculate** how many times the radio button that have been clicked each answer.

Here the jquery function in file js:

```
$("input[type=radio]").change(function () {
      let valueButton = $(":radio:checked").val();
      let totalChecked = $(":radio:checked").length;
      let totalAccept = $('input[value="Accept"]:radio:checked').length;
      let totalReject = $('input[value="Reject"]:radio:checked').length;
      $("#showAccept").text((totalAccept / totalChecked) * 100+"%");
      $("#showReject").text((totalReject / totalChecked) * 100+"%");
      // console.log(valueButton);
      // console.log(totalChecked);
      // console.log(totalAccept);
      // console.log(totalReject);
    });
```

The `label` that show how many percentage each answer, add some `id` in label:

```
<section>
  <h2>Cumplimiento 1</h2>
  <form class="form3">
    <fieldset class="Compliance">
      <label class="form3header1" for="complianceperc">Cumplimiento (%)</label>
      <span class="percentage" type="number" id="complianceperc" name="complianceperc"></span>

      <label class="form3item1" for="yescount">Sí (cantidad)</label>
      <span id="showAccept" class="counter">0</span>
      <label class="form3item2" for="yescount">No (cantidad)</label>
      <span class="counter" id="showReject">0</span>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</section>
```

And i added two input in this case, to show the labels percentage are running properly:

```
<!-- 1 -->
<label class="form4item1">1. ¿El Asesor de Servicio comienza a atender al Cliente en los primeros 2 minutos?</label>
<input class="form4item1radio1" type="radio" name="question1" id="a" value="Accept">
<input class="form4item1radio2" type="radio" name="question1" id="b" value="Reject">
<textarea class="form4item1comment" placeholder="Escribe tus notas aquí"></textarea>

<!-- 2 -->
<br>
<label class="form4item1">1. ¿El Asesor de Servicio comienza a atender al Cliente en los primeros 2 minutos?</label>
<input class="form4item1radio1" type="radio" name="question2" id="a" value="Accept">
<input class="form4item1radio2" type="radio" name="question2" id="b" value="Reject">
<textarea class="form4item1comment" placeholder="Escribe tus notas aquí"></textarea>
```

And here is the overall of the code:

```js
$("input[type=radio]").change(function () {
  let valueButton = $(":radio:checked").val();
  let totalChecked = $(":radio:checked").length;
  let totalAccept = $('input[value="Accept"]:radio:checked').length;
  let totalReject = $('input[value="Reject"]:radio:checked').length;
  $("#showAccept").text((totalAccept / totalChecked) * 100+"%");
  $("#showReject").text((totalReject / totalChecked) * 100+"%");
  // console.log(valueButton);
  // console.log(totalChecked);
  // console.log(totalAccept);
  // console.log(totalReject);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <h2>Cumplimiento 1</h2>
  <form class="form3">
    <fieldset class="Compliance">
      <label class="form3header1" for="complianceperc">Cumplimiento (%)</label>
      <span class="percentage" type="number" id="complianceperc" name="complianceperc"></span>
      
      <label class="form3item1" for="yescount">Sí (cantidad)</label>
      <span id="showAccept" class="counter">0</span>
      
      <label class="form3item2" for="yescount">No (cantidad)</label>
      <span class="counter" id="showReject">0</span>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</section>

<!-- Label 1 -->
<label class="form4item1">1. ¿El Asesor de Servicio comienza a atender al Cliente en los primeros 2 minutos?</label>
<input class="form4item1radio1" type="radio" name="question1" id="a" value="Accept">
<input class="form4item1radio2" type="radio" name="question1" id="b" value="Reject">
<textarea class="form4item1comment" placeholder="Escribe tus notas aquí"></textarea>

<!-- Label 2 -->
<br>
<label class="form4item1">1. ¿El Asesor de Servicio comienza a atender al Cliente en los primeros 2 minutos?</label>
<input class="form4item1radio1" type="radio" name="question2" id="a" value="Accept">
<input class="form4item1radio2" type="radio" name="question2" id="b" value="Reject">
<textarea class="form4item1comment" placeholder="Escribe tus notas aquí"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Aditya! This is what I was looking for. Best.

Comment: You are welcome, it would be a pleasure if you  vote up my answer if you like it ;)

Comment: Dear Aditya, please let me know if there's a way to reach out to you (if you are OK with it and it isn't against the rules of the site.) Thank you in advance.